# Eliminating NHibernate collection type in Domain entity

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a domain entity that exposes a collection type (`Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Idea>`) from NHibernate. The class is mapped via NHibernate mapping by code. But I don't like the collection type, `Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Idea>`, which is a NHibernate type. I want to replace it with .Net collection type.

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Idea> Ideas { get; protected set; }
}

public class PersonMap : ClassMapping<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `ISet<T>` with .NET's `ICollection<T>`, and initialize it with .NET `HashSet<T>` instead of the Iesi `HashedSet<T>`.

Reference [Ayende's blog](http://ayende.com/blog/3971/nhibernate-tidbit-using-set-without-referencing-iesi-collections).

If you don't need the set semantics, then you can use bag semantics as Alex's answer suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by following this article:

http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/03/15/using-lt-set-gt-in-mappings-without-iesi-collections-net-4.aspx

If you do not want to use the nuget package then:

1) Copy Paste this code. I think it is the same as the one in the nugetpackage
https://gist.github.com/mynkow/5580319

2) Copy Paste this configuration when you are configuring the session factory:

```
cfg.Properties[NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.CollectionTypeFactoryClass] = typeof(Net4CollectionTypeFactory).AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

3) Remove the assembly reference to Iesi. You will still need it but it will be copied automatically on build with NHibernate.dll to the output folder.

Kudos Jose Romaniello

Answer (score 0):

Just use the IList<> from system.Collections.Generic.
I know this works when mapping the collection as a NHibernate Bag.

Because U have a ISet I presume that u map the collection as a NHibernate Set, I'm not certain it works on that too.
If it works that's it else consider mapping the collection as Bag.

We do mapping through .hbm.xml mapping files so I can't give U an example of in code mapping a Bag, but there are plenty of sites that discribe that :)

Mapping .hbm.xml example:

```
<bag name="Ideas" table="SomeTable" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true" lazy="false">
        <key column="Id"/>
        <one-to-many class="Idea"/>
    </bag>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is the xml code you provide a one-to-many relationship. What does inverse="true" do? Must I always specify Many-to-one on the other side.

Comment: Depending on your relation you **could** map the `Idea` as a one-to-one, in case when a `Idea` always belongs to a specific `Person` and could not be shared over multiple 'Person's. If you create this relation you should add a property 'Person' to the 'Idea' class so the 'Idea' class knows who it's parent is. If not done cascading will not work. (deleting childs when parent is deleted). I say you could create this relation because this relation doesn't have to exists for it to work.